# Minimum bandpass bandwidth?

Tags: bandpass, bandwidth

Is there any restriction on decreasing the bandwidth (beyond the sampling rate) that I should be aware of when filtering a signal with a bandpass? My intuition tells me that the quality of the result may compromised if the frequencies too close to each other but I can't see why. Is there any mathematical or rule of thumb expression that allows me to know when the bandwidth is too small?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no theoretical limits and you can find applications with extremely narrow bandpass filters (like a PLL for example).

The main tradeoff is that the bandwidth limits how quickly the output can change. The narrower the filter, so slower the output will vary. For a very narrow filter the output will become just an amplitude modulated sine wave and the speed of of the modulation decreases the more narrow it gets. In the extreme case of an infinitely narrow filter you just end up with a steady state sine wave as the output.

In some applications that's exactly what you want but in others, it's not.

There can also be practical issues of numerical precision and noise, but that depends on the details of application and implementation.